# Can't delete user through Http post request in ASP.NET Identity 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Here is my code :

```
    [HttpPost("{id}")]
    [Route("DeleteUserProfile")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUserProfile(string id) 
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        _app.Users.Remove(user);
        await _app.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

    }
```

_app is my Context. Is my approach to deleting AspNetUsers right? When I Post a request in Postman, i get 404 not found. Please help! My url is : http://localhost:57392/api/UserProfile/DeleteUserProfile/292207c9-e961-4073-b9b8-260e86f7cbe0.

Comment: Instead of having the `Route` attribute try changing the `HttpPost` attribute to: `HttpPost("DeleteUserProfile/{id}")`. Also you probably shouldn't use a `POST` when `DELETE` perfectly fits the action that's done. That also means you don't necessarily need the `DeleteUserProfile` in the path.

Comment: Have you configured a RoutePrefix for "api/UserProfile"?

Comment: 404, i did. I get no route matches the supplied values. I have to check that error, but i don't know why it doesn't work since getallusers() method works like charm...

Comment: It works, I just have to change the parameters in RedirectToAction(), my problem was Routing,should have put  [HttpDelete("DeleteUserProfile/{id}")] without Route part.Thanks guys :D

Answer (score 1):

I should not have put Route, proper http request is :

```
[HttpDelete("DeleteUserProfile/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUserProfile(string id) 
    {
        var user = await _app.Users.FindAsync(id);
        if (user == null) 
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        _app.Users.Remove(user);
        await _app.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("GetAllUsers","UserProfile",);

    }
```